# Pass multiple files to AutodeskForge Design Automation API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

If i use just 1 file it works perfectly, but with more than 1 it fails
This is my request

```
{ 
   "Arguments":{ 
      "InputArguments":[ 
         { 
            "Resource":"https://s3url.com",
            "Name":"HostDwg1-050A-014"
         },
         { 
            "Resource":"https://s3url.com",
            "Name":"HostDwg1-050A-015"
         }
      ],
      "OutputArguments":[ 
         { 
            "Name":"Result1-050A-014",
            "HttpVerb":"PUT",
            "Resource":"https:://s3url.com",
            "StorageProvider":"Generic"
         },
         { 
            "Name":"Result1-050A-015",
            "HttpVerb":"PUT",
            "Resource":"https://s3url.com",
            "StorageProvider":"Generic"
         }
      ]
   },
   "ActivityId":"PlotToPDF",
   "Id":""
}
```

This is the error i get

```
The number of Arguments is bigger than the number of Parameters.
Parameter name: Count
```

How have to be done the request to convert more than one file, without doing a request for each file? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PlotToPDF activity  declares exactly one input parameter and exactly one output parameter. An activity is like a function in a programming language: you can only provide as many arguments as there are parameters. So...

1. If you want to have a workitem that has more than one input/output argument then you should define an new custom activity that has more than one input/output parameters.
2. If you want plot multiple files then you should simply submit multiple workitems.

Comment: Do you know where i can find a documentation on how to create the custom activity? i can't find anything on the forge documentation or with google